# PostgreSQL Simple supports only up 10 variables in a tuple, but I need more

Tags: postgresql, haskell, postgresql-simple

I have a postgresql table with a bunch of columns, it's around 20-30 columns. Posgresql Simple supports only up 10 variables in a tuple https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.0.0/candidate/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-ToRow.html#v:toRow

It's not enough for me. How can I fix that? I can't use the original "data" I have. If I use it for insertion then the "id" and other fields generated by Postgresql will be passed from a client and it'll cause an exception.

Creating a new "data"  and then implementing `FromJson` and possibly other intances might be overkill. Then is there any other solution?

Comment: You should be able to make your own instance of FromRow that can compose either a tuple of the size you need, or some other data type that you can use.

Comment: and as a 30-tuple would be horrible (the constraints for the instance alone would be insane) I would suggest writing a simple `data` structure and to make it into `FromRow` - just copy&past/adapt from [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.0.0/candidate/docs/src/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-ToRow.html#toRow)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [(:.)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.0.0/candidate/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-Types.html#t::.) operator to combine several tuples into one row. There are instances defined for both [FromRow](https://github.com/lpsmith/postgresql-simple/blob/master/src/Database/PostgreSQL/Simple/FromRow.hs#L261-L262) and [ToRow](https://github.com/lpsmith/postgresql-simple/blob/master/src/Database/PostgreSQL/Simple/ToRow.hs#L95-L96)